# Where is Process Control Block saved?

Tags: switch-statement, controls

My question is where is PCB of process A is saved when it's happening a context switch(so when the processor takes the process B). Somebody told me that is saved in the kernel memory, but I didn't understand at all..so is it saved in RAM , is it saved on the processor cache?

Comment: what language are you working with? operating system? your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to know what you are asking.

Comment: Operating Systems...I want to understand the concept

Comment: I guess my comment wasn't clear:  I was asking what language are you working with? *what* operating system are you working with?

Comment: I'm not working with a specific operating system....I just want to understand some concepts about operating systems...let's say that I'm interested in Windows

Answer (score -1):

Different operating systems are built different ways.  With that said, in general, when a context switch happens, the state of the process being switched out is saved and either a new context is loaded for a new process being started, or the previously saved context of an already-running process is loaded.  The context is saved in RAM, any other storage would be much to slow to be practical.

The processor cache isn't addressable memory in any system I'm aware of, so "storing saved context in processor cache" isn't something the operating system can do directly.